# Python shape gives incorrect result

Tags: python

I am using pylibtiff to read an image with get_samples function.
The error is:

```
arr[i:i + xxx] = d ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1360) into shape (1347)
```

I modified the code near the error point to find the bug:

```
if compression == 1:  # none
    d = self.data[start:end]
elif compression == 5:  # lzw
    d = self.data[start:end]
    d = tif_lzw.decode(d, bytes_per_strip)
print(compression, d, d.shape, d.nbytes, i, i + d.nbytes)
print(d.nbytes, arr[i:i + d.nbytes].shape)
arr[i:i + d.nbytes] = d
i += d.nbytes
```

Yet I still get the result:

```
5 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0] (1360,) 1360 82305853 82307213 

1360 (1347,)
```

How is that even possible? d.nbytes is 1360, is is 82305853, i +d.nbytes = 82307213. Where does the 1347 come from?

Comment: It would probably help people to post a full snippet with link to the tiff  source to reproduce the issue...

Comment: Try printing out the length of ``arr`` - I think you will find that it is 82305853 + 1347 bytes long, so that your slice ``i:i+d.nbytes`` extends slightly beyond the end of the array and gets silently truncated.

Comment: yeah, it is that way. the error is due to the short size of the array.